# Get .exe from scrapy-splash python project

Tags: scrapy, exe, pyinstaller, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm having a scrapy-splash project and I'm trying to get a `.exe` file with this setup.py script:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from stockproject.spiders.spider import Scrape

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(Scrape)
process.start()
```

Now pyinstaller give the `.exe` file, but the problem is that my splash is running on docker and I don't know how to install it on end-users computer.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot about this problem since I posted this question, But there is no possible way to do this, one of the best replacement is to use `mechanize` browser instead.